# Ruby alternative to .each() working with one item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting tired of using if loops because the `.each` function is not working when applied to one object.

For example :

```
@groups = ...
users = User.find(params[:selected_users])

if params[:selected_users].count == 1  # case with one object
  users.some_method()
else                          # case with multiple objects
  users.each do |user|
    user.some_method()
  end
end
```

Is there a function that would do the same as `.each` and that would simply return the object when applied to one object ?

Comment: if params[:selected_users].count == 1  # case with one object
  users.some_method()
else                          # case with multiple objects
  users.each do |user|
    user.some_method()
  end
end in this do we have different methods? eg some_method() or both are same

Comment: There's something wrong with your code. If you pass an array (of ids) to [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find), it returns an array, even if the array contains only one id: `User.find([1]) #=> [#<User id: 1>]`.

Comment: @Sanket yes the methods are the same.
You're right @Stefan, so I think writing `users = User.find([params[:selected_users]])` would probably be the best solution.

Comment: @user284130 You're calling `params[:selected_users].count`, so `params[:selected_users]` already is an array, isn't it?

Comment: There's also `where` method. You're using wrong method, no wonder you have to do strange things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to this:

```
users = Array.wrap(User.find(params[:selected_users]))
#users is now always an array
users.each do |user|
  # do stuff
end
```

`Array.wrap` handles some edge cases better than `Array()`

For example:

```
x = {a: "b", c: "d"}

Array(x)
# => [[:a, "b"], [:c, "d"]]

Array.wrap(x)
# =>[{:a=>"b", :c=>"d"}]
```

Comment: Adding extra brackets in the `find()` method as @Stefan suggested is smarter, in other cases (when using scopes for example) I will use your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write:

```
Array(users).each do |user|
  user.some_method
end
```

Some examples what `Array()` does. If called with a single argument:

```
> Array(:foo)
# => [:foo]
```

If called with something that is already an array:

```
> Array([:foo])
# => [:foo]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`find_each`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each)

```
User.where(id: params[:selected_users]).find_each do |user|
  user.some_method
end
```

This isn't going to work if you want to do something with them afterword though.  I've just noticed your `@groups` if you need to use them in a view afterwards then you'll need one of the other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to an array `arr` with `each`:

```
arr.each{|e| ...} #=> arr
```

you can do to a single object `obj` with `tap`:

```
obj.tap{|e| ...} #=> obj
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that all answer intend to solve the problem linked to ActiveRecord.

However, another option could be to extend each to every Object, so iteartion happens only on the object itself.

Exemple:

```
class Object
  def each
   if block_given?
     [self].each { |e| yield(e) }
   end
end
```

I am not an export in core Ruby, so I don't know what could be the side effects, but it seems to work....

```
1.each{|i|puts i}
=> [1]
[1,2,3].each{|i|puts i}
=> [1, 2, 3]
```